# How come the cosmological constant supports the idea of dark energy existing?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

According to an article I've read recently, the cosmological constant was used to support the theory of dark energy. But the cosmological constant already defines an inclination in the essence of cosmos. And the dark energy is also a force that causes the galaxies to move away from each other with a growing acceleration. So if they cause the same things to happen eventually, wouldn't they disagree with each other and can not exist at the same time? Is it me lacking knowledge about these terms or did I get the article wrong?

Comment: What article in particular?

Comment: it was written by hubert reeves and the name would probably be translated as "critical view of dark energy" or sth like that (i didin't read the article in english). However i don't think it can be found online

Comment: beware of bad translations and fakes , Hubert Reeves supports the dark energy concept ... Dark energy , in some theories , is the cosmological constant , the quintessence

Comment: i see.. i guess it's me lacking knowledge about cosmological constant. thank you for the help!

Comment: as explained in the answer of the similar question : sorry, a mistake in my above comment,  the quintessence is another dark energy solution